# Search DataSet and Display Multiple Results(Rows) in TextBoxes

Tags: c#, search, dataset

I would like to search my DataSet for a customer name, this name will occur more than once throughout the dataset, meaning there will be more than 1 result (multiple rows returned)

When my search button is clicked, form2 opens up, and in theory should display all rows containing the customer name, but how do I achive this?

I can get it to display 1 row without a problem, but how would I make it display all rows, and the data in textboxes.

At the moment I am using a foreach loop to fill text boxes with returned data, but this only takes data from 1 row within my DataSet.

Is there a way I can make my form auto generate textboxes and populate them will all the data from the array? When I run my query at the moment, it fills the textboxes on form2 with the last rotation of the foreach.

[DB Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e4k5.png)

Appreciate any help

Adam

```
 DataRow[] returnedRows;

        returnedRows = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"].Select("cust_name='" + searchFor + "'");

        foreach (DataRow returned in returnedRows)
        {
            tbName.Text = returned[1].ToString();
            tbAddress.Text = returned[2].ToString();
            tbPhone.Text = returned[3].ToString();

            tbMake.Text = returned[4].ToString();
            tbModel.Text = returned[5].ToString();
            tbReg.Text = returned[6].ToString();
            tbYear.Text = returned[7].ToString();

            tbParts1.Text = returned[8].ToString();
            tbParts2.Text = returned[9].ToString();
            tbParts3.Text = returned[10].ToString();
            tbParts3.Text = returned[11].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Why don't use for example a datagriview to display every rows you got in your dataset ? Textbox will just display one value not several . Did you think about it ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having just a single value appear is that you're setting the text of your text boxes to a new value for each row that you've selected. You could change your code to instead add to the Text in the the Textboxes:

```
tbName.Text += returned[1].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Or you could instead bind it to a DataGridView, which is designed to display tabular data. Assuming the DataGridView was named something like customerDataView,

```
returnedRows = ds.Tables["Table_Data_1"].Select("cust_name='" + searchFor + "'");
var newTable = returnedRows.CopyToDataTable();
BindingSource bindSource = new BindingSource();
bindSource.DataSource = newTable;
var customerDataView.DataSource = bindSource;
```

Comment: Great work, thanks! I had to modify that code a little though, removed the var from the last 3 lines, and added BingingSource at the start of line 3.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If this has answered your question, please mark the answer as Accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate textboxes dinamicaly 
Its something like this

```
foreach (DataRow returned in returnedRows)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = "textBox1"; //generate id dinamically can be a count
    txt.Text = returned[1].ToString();
    form1.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

The way you've implemented the loop override the data in each interation

I've improved the sample code from following this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2229040/5252904 answer provided by @rahul.