# How to add a button to SAP B1 UserForm in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sapb1

I wanna add a button,checkbox,tabcontrol and something like that with code. How can i do this?

Actually i wanna add something to tabcontrol.

I am using C#.

Answer (score 1):

ref:[How to dynamically generate a TextBox control.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229019/how-to-dynamically-generate-a-textbox-control)

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();

txt.ID = "textBox1";

txt.Text = "txtbox";

tabcontrol1.Controls.Add(txt);

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "Lbl";

tabcontrol1.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Comment: where should i write this?  In  the function?                                                                 private void Form_LoadBefore(SAPbouiCOM.SBOItemEventArg pVal, out bool BubbleEvent)
        {
        }        @kattav-mauk

Comment: add your code in Constructors
 public Form()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
//here

     }

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the SDK samples, you have a lot of examples on how to do it.