# 'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ID'

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code to create a textbox on each button click:

```
private void AddNewTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int timerCount = 0;
    int boxY = 0;
    if (timerCount <= 6)
    {
        timerCount++;
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "timer" + timerCount++;
        txt.Text = Convert.ToString(timerCount);
        txt.Name = Convert.ToString(timerCount);
        txt.Width = 63;
        txt.Location = new Point(0, boxY);
        TimerContainer.Controls.Add(txt);
        boxY = boxY + 25;
    }
}
```

`txt.ID = timerCount++;` gives me `'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ID'`, although it is described in answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229019/how-to-dynamically-generate-a-textbox-contro]) question and on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing ASP.Net and Windows Forms. In ASP.Net you have `ID`. In Windows Form, you access controls through the `Name` property.

Update:

Your code is actually creating multiple textbox but the location is same. You Y coordinate is getting reset every time. You might want to make `boxY` a private member.

Comment: Am I able to add ASP.Net somehow to my current project? Are `Name` in Windows Forms and `ID` in ASP.Net equal? If so, I'm changing the `Name` for every next TextBox, but there's still only one that is created.

Comment: No they are two different technologies. ASP.Net is used to make web based applications while Windows Forms are used to create desktop applications (something you install)

Comment: I accidentally updated my previous comment instead of a new.

Comment: WinForms' textbox has `.Tag` if it helps :-)