# c# add text boxes together

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering if there is a way to group 2 textboxes and 3 checkboxes together in c#. I need to make 37 of these 5 boxes and I think making them manually in the design view would be inefficient. I'm not sure where to start I thought of making a class but I don't think it's possible to make a textbox a property of a class. The boxes also need to have different names so they don't conflict with each other.

[image: Boxes]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229019/how-to-dynamically-generate-a-textbox-control

Comment: Create a UserControls. Creattion of Composite Controls is one the UserControl's Goals.

Comment: create custom control or use groupbox but it will not mask the controls under is wings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestions I did end up using a user control. Here is what I did to make 37 dynamic boxes

```
while (count < 36)
            {
if (count >= 1)
{
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        x = 50;
        y = y + 320;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 450;
    }
}
if (count == 1)
{
    y = 80;
}

var question = new Questions();

question.questions_Descriptionbox.Name = questionNames[count] + "_Descriptionbox";
question.questions_Descriptionbox.Text = question.questions_Descriptionbox.Name + count + " Y: " + y + " X:" + x + " Name:" + name;
question.questions_Descriptionbox.Location = new Point(x, y);

y = y + 70;

question.questions_checkboxok.Name = questionNames[count] + "_Okcheckbox";
question.questions_checkboxok.Text = question.questions_checkboxok.Name;
question.questions_checkboxok.Location = new Point(x, y);

x = x + 120;

question.questions_checkboxwarning.Name = questionNames[count] + "_Warningcheckbox";
question.questions_checkboxwarning.Text = question.questions_checkboxwarning.Name;
question.questions_checkboxwarning.Location = new Point(x, y);

x = question.questions_Descriptionbox.Location.X + 235;

question.questions_checkboxneedsattention.Name = questionNames[count] + "_NeedsAttentioncheckbox";
question.questions_checkboxneedsattention.Text = question.questions_checkboxneedsattention.Name;
question.questions_checkboxneedsattention.Location = new Point(x, y);

x = question.questions_Descriptionbox.Location.X;
y = y + 50;

question.questions_notebox.Name = questionNames[count] + "_Notecheckbox";
question.questions_notebox.Text = question.questions_notebox.Name;
question.questions_notebox.Location = new Point(x, y);


this.Controls.Add(question.questions_Descriptionbox);
this.Controls.Add(question.questions_checkboxok);
this.Controls.Add(question.questions_checkboxwarning);
this.Controls.Add(question.questions_checkboxneedsattention);
this.Controls.Add(question.questions_notebox);
count++;
    }
```

the descriptionbox.text is just to verify that it is working the way it should.